# NoSQL: Document-oriented design/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, document-oriented-db, database, nosql

I'm trying to use a documented-oriented database but I can't get the design right.

Mainly, I want a database that can store Planes, Seats, Passengers, and very importantly - Changes in seats that passengers have done in a particular Plane with their timpestamp.

I will need to do queries on getting all seats from a plane, all taken seats from a plane, all passengers from a plane, all passengers that at some point chose a particular seat, all seats that a passenger has chosen in a plane and most popular seats.

In a relational database, I would just use 2 or 3 many-to-many relations with their associated junction tables, but I don't know how to do this in document-oriented database. Right now the Plane has a list of references to both Seats and Passengers; and Seats and Passengers reference each other. This doesn't work because I don't know where to keep the timestamp of the seat change. I suppose I need another (kind of junction) table for it but not really sure how to do it correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Your schema design should be something like this:

```
{  //Flight Collection, helps query Available and Booked seats
  "Flight_id":"A",
  "FlightName":"CoolAir",
  "AvailableSeats":["A1","A2"],
  "BookedSeats":["A3","A4"]
}
{  //Seats Collection, helps query current/previous passenger
  "SeatId":"A1",
  "Flight_id":"A",
  "AllPreviousPassengers":[{"P2",TimeStamp1},{"P3",TimeStamp2}],
  "CurrentPassenger":{"P1",TimeStamp3}
}
{//Passenger collection, helps query passenger details
  "PassengerId":"P1",
  "PassengerName":"Mr. ABC",
  "SeatId":"A1",
  "Flight_id":"A"
}
```

For your use-case, this is roughly how the schema should look like. Joins will be required in code.